# Optimizing a simple calculus using a list of matrices - Repeated dot product between a vector and a list of matrices

Tags: performance-tuning, matrix

I want to make the following operation :

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \dot q_1\\\dot q_2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 \end{bmatrix} \mathbf A_1 \begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2 \end{bmatrix} \\ \begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 \end{bmatrix} \mathbf A_2 \begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2 \end{bmatrix}  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \dot q_1\\\dot q_2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\ 1&1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2 \end{bmatrix} \\ \begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1&0\\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2 \end{bmatrix}  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \dot q_1\\\dot q_2 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} {q_1}^2 + q_2(q_1+q_2)\\ -{q_1}^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

I also want to put the two $\mathbf A_1$ and $\mathbf A_2$ matrices inside a list of matrices `A` in mathematica.

So I started creating my list of matrices `A` and did the following :

```
A={{{0, 1}, {1, 1}},{{-1, 0}, {0, 0}}};
res={{q1, q2}.A[[1]].{q1, q2},{q1, q2}.A[[2]].{q1, q2}};
final={q1p,q2p}+res;
```

Now, my question : is there a way to optimize the calculation of `res`? The goal is to avoid calling `A[[1]]` and `A[[2]]` independently each time. The perspective is to extend the `A` list to a list of dimension $n \gt 2$ (something like this) :

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \dot q_1\\\dot q_2 \\ \vdots \\ \dot q_n \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 & \cdots & q_n\end{bmatrix} \mathbf A_1 \begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2 \\ \vdots \\ \dot q_n  \end{bmatrix} \\ \begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 & \cdots & q_n  \end{bmatrix} \mathbf A_2 \begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2 \\ \vdots \\ \dot q_n  \end{bmatrix}  \\ \vdots \\ \begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 & \cdots & q_n  \end{bmatrix} \mathbf A_n \begin{bmatrix} q_1\\ q_2 \\ \vdots \\ q_n  \end{bmatrix} \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Use `/@` like `{q1,q2}.#.{q1,q2}&/@A`.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Ok I'm embarrassed... Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Voted to close, but you can now post a detailed answer to your own question

Comment: Per belisarius, please do post a detailed answer, it may help others who come looking for a similar problem.

Comment: This also works: `A.q.q`, where `q = {q1, q2, ..., qn}`.  (Assuming the dot on righthandmost $q_n$ is a typo.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so, thanks to Spawn1701D's comment here's the simplest way to proceed :

```
A={{{0, 1}, {1, 1}},{{-1, 0}, {0, 0}}};
res={q1,q2}.#.{q1,q2}&/@A;
final={q1p,q2p}+res;
```

To state it simple, Spawn1701D prescribes the usage of pure functions to make it extremely terse :

- `#` function creates a slot between the two versions of the $\mathbf q$ vector
- `/@` is a shorthand of the `Map` function

Basically what this code does is : map the `Dot` operations to every element on the `A` list (which in this particular case is a list of matrices).

**UPDATE**

Another way to proceed (the simplest one in fact, thanks Michael E2) is to simply use the `Dot` product twice between the list `A` and vector `q`

```
q={q1,q2}
A={{{0, 1}, {1, 1}},{{-1, 0}, {0, 0}}};
res=A.q.q
```

Comment: Note that `/@` is just shorthand for `Map`, not a "pure function version". You can use `/@` with named functions as in `f /@ {1,2,3}` and you can use `Map` with pure functions as in `Map[2# &, {1,2,3}]`